# how to increase primary key value automatically in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

how can i create an id as 1401cid001 where 14 is year 01 is month of january and cid is comman textand 001 will increase automatically. now 14 must increase every new year and 01 must increase at starting of new month. both of above must not affect the last three numbers, as they only get to start again after year is increased. please help

Comment: 1) That's incredibly STUPID to do. 2) For such purposes, you create triggers that invoke stored procedures or functions that do that. 3) There is **no built-in** mechanism for something like that. And 4) but not unimportant, please learn about databases before doing something incredibly dumb like this, creating a primary key in some weird format without even knowing what PK is used for, it's simply a crime against relational data.

Comment: @N.B. I think you're a little harsh. The OP likely just needs a unique  index on multiple columns including id month and year. No need to make him feel foolish.

Comment: @madebydavid - it's also harsh to call fat people fat, so a new word was invented - obese. It's the same thing. **Stupid** is the right term in this context, and it's _not_ aimed at the OP in terms of making him feel bad. However, there's dime a dozen of these questions, and lack of research is just downright insulting.

Comment: @N.B.-I thought it would be easy to understand for users. I thought by just looking at 1401cid001 will let user to understand the date of entry of id in the table. It was a question. You don't need to be judgmental about me. Anyways i appreciate your concerns

Comment: @user3227823 - I'm not judgmental, problem is that someone will google something similar and arrive at same "idea" which is not how you should be using this technology. If you want to have some sort of custom identifier or a special column used for displaying purposes, you don't tamper with primary key. You can create a trigger (after insert / before update) that will create a string based on your specification and add it to the row, then just use that string to show it to the user. Don't modify the PK, that's the worst thing you can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this,

Create another table and maintain reference of primary key...

suppose you have table users,

```
id, name, email, password
```

and you want to add key like `1401cid001` 
use another table `user_meta`

```
id, user_id, user_unique_id
```

in this table, **user_id** is from `users` table, and **user_unique_id** is your unique key...

Comment: thank you. I understand now. can you show me some examples in mysql to implement

Answer (score 1):

You would never use something like this as your primary key. If there is some really compelling use case that would require you to have something like this, it could easily be built by storing a standard auto-increment ID, create_date, command, and possibly sequence_number.

Comment: ok i will generate a primary key as normal, then should i use unique key as per my query.

Comment: Like I mentioned, you can generate what you call the unique key for display using the data. It's probably not necessary to store it as a string in the DB unless that makes other processes easier.